# How to get a dictionary object from a string value in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
[
    {
      'address': 'f5f891c1009db80a4fabd7c329bbc58068c5796aef6c4547fbd155c775b946843b757d'
    },
    {
      'owner': '02876ba3dab1013b568e20a961522090b83e8ce0d3f797b2e795d445089db50767'
    },
    "{'name': 'f5f891c1006142efc3c6ea431f2c5d8bd794cbe9a1695f6112586aad2d9e799e535f6b', 'quantity': '22', 'has_link': True, 'address': 'f5f891c1006142efc3c6ea431f2c5d8bd794cbe9a1695f6112586aad2d9e799e535f6b'}" ]
```

The last value is a string of dictionary which is

```
"{'name': 'f5f891c1006142efc3c6ea431f2c5d8bd794cbe9a1695f6112586aad2d9e799e535f6b', 'quantity': '22', 'has_link': True, 'address': 'f5f891c1006142efc3c6ea431f2c5d8bd794cbe9a1695f6112586aad2d9e799e535f6b'}"
```

how can I get it in this format, the double quotation completely remove

```
{'name': 'f5f891c1006142efc3c6ea431f2c5d8bd794cbe9a1695f6112586aad2d9e799e535f6b', 'quantity': '22', 'has_link': True, 'address': 'f5f891c1006142efc3c6ea431f2c5d8bd794cbe9a1695f6112586aad2d9e799e535f6b'}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast

d = "{'name': 'f5f891c1006142efc3c6ea431f2c5d8bd794cbe9a1695f6112586aad2d9e799e535f6b', 'quantity': '22', 'has_link': True, 'address': 'f5f891c1006142efc3c6ea431f2c5d8bd794cbe9a1695f6112586aad2d9e799e535f6b'}"

print(ast.literal_eval(d))
```

Comment: Thanks Austin, it works!